# Glass goes into endless crash loop after OEM unlock

Tags: google-glass

After doing `fastboot oem unlock`, my Glass now endlessly pops up a "Camera has stopped" message. The unlock turned off USB debug so I can't check logs with ADB, and the message pops up too fast to navigate. I flashed the xe-12 boot image but still no luck and no USB debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was bad hardware; I eventually contacted support and got a replacement.